# How do I adjust for overproduction from Industry?

Tags: simcity-2013

Every low density industrial buildings product 9 freight every 2hours 24minutes.

And medium density industrial buildings product 9 freight every 1hour 12minutes.

And high density industrial buildings product 9 freight every 36minutes. It's going faster.

Low and medium buildings are fine if the traffic is fluent. They don't claim about shipping problem.

But high density buildings are keep claiming for shipping freights. Because their production speed is faster than their shipping speed.

I've build trade depots right next to them, but still have the problem.

Should I just destroy them out?

What can I do?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, your high density industrial buildings are producing more freight supply than the demand of your city? Is this an issue of supply/demand or traffic congestion? You say you placed trade depots next to them. Is the freight storage of the depots full, or are the high density industrial buildings just not delivering freight to them?

Comment: High density industrial buildings deliver freights, but the freight production speed is faster(they produce so many freights, deliver truck can't handle it!) than delivering speed. As a result, freights are piling up in the factorie, it causes "We want to ship our freights!".

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. Can I reword your question to, "How do I adjust for overproduction from Industry?". I think that is the underlying issue you are having.

Answer (score 3):

Industry buildings spawn trucks every hour (each building has its own timer).

Suppose a building generates a truck at 9:15.  The next truck is scheduled at 10:15 and will not generate if the first truck isn't back yet.  Then 11:15, 12:15, 1:15...

Trucks from different density industrial buildings carry different amounts of freight and look different.

If you get at least 8 trucks/day out of your building, you'll be fine.

If you want to maximize stability of freight shipments, make sure that the truck cannot leave the industrial area without passing a trade depot with available space in its freight shipping addon.  (either side of the street, or right side of the avenue - nothing crosses avenue medians).

The real problem with HD industry buildings and shipments is the number of workers.  Workers leave by the same exit as the freight.  If the HD building has between 600 and 1620 workers, it could take hours for those workers to exit the building (and freight will wait).  Solve this by making workers walk or take street cars (don't use buses as they will cause tears).

Answer (score 1):

**Possible solutions:**

1. Augment existing trade depots
2. Zone more commercial
3. Dezone the offending industrial and rezone or leave it alone

1) If you don't have traffic congestion problems, you could add more delivery truck or freight storage modules to your existing trade depots. [David B](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115713/how-do-i-adjust-for-overproduction-from-industry/115842#115842) explained this solution in detail.

2) You could also zone more commercial if you have the space, which would increase the demand for freight and consume more of the supply.

3) I suggest dezoning the areas with the complaining high density industry. However, I recommend you **do not** just delete the buildings. This could lead to some [unwanted consequences](http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/9361396.page) and break your city. If you delete buildings with workers in them, the workers may disappear completely instead of being reassigned to a new job.

**My Recommendation: Solution 3**

Dezone the industrial and rezone with residential or commercial. To do this, go to the zoning panel and select the option with the red X. This will allow you to remove parts of a zone. You can then rezone with residential or commercial.

When you rezone over existing buildings, the ones that become abandoned or make low profits will be removed by the game engine and will be replaced by the building type of the new zone. You may have to do some urban renewal by placing parks and other happiness boosting buildings, but it will be worth it in the long run.

This solution is best IMO, because it removes buildings that are struggling "naturally". This is usually how I strike a good balance in my cities, and this is sort of how governments do it in the real world.